# How to force Javascript to wait for an ajax call that is being called from a separate function

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint

Here's the short version. I have a function that runs an ajax call to get some data, parses the data, and returns it as an array. When I call this function, javascript continues executing code before the ajax call has finished.

Here's the structure of the function

```
function GetList(listName, heads, gibberish){
  var items;
  var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+ listName + "')/items";
  $.when(
    $.ajax({
      url: siteUrl,
      method: "GET",
      headers: { Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" },
      success: function(data) {
        var listItems = data.d.results;
        items = listItems;
      }
    })
  ).done(function() {
    console.log(items);
    items = parseList(items, heads, gibberish);
    return items;
```

Now if I just run the $.when and ajax call outside of the function and assign the results to a variable, I can put whatever I want to do in the .done and it works as I want it to.

But calling this function like this

```
var heads = ["Title", "Artist", "Plays", "Added", "Genre"];
var gibbe = ["Title", "mz0o", "hd1f", "v9gk", "nphg"];

array = GetList("Music", heads, gibbe);

console.log("Array: ", array);
```

The console log for array is returning undefined before the function finishes running. The output of the above code is

Array: undefined
Items: [[The unprocessed data]]

So even though the function doesn't return data till the ajax call is completed, the rest of the page is executing regardless.

And I've tested it like this and it works as it should.

```
  var items;
  var listName = 'Music';
  var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+ listName + "')/items";
  $.when(
    $.ajax({
      url: siteUrl,
      method: "GET",
      headers: { Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" },
      success: function(data) {
        var listItems = data.d.results;
        items = listItems;
      }
    })
  ).done(function() {
    console.log(items);
    var array = parseList(items, heads, gibberish);
    console.log("Array: ", array);
```

That gives me properly formatted data I can work with.

So is there a way to force javascript to wait until (in the previous code) array is no longer undefined? 
I tried sticking that part of it in a $.when and putting the rest of the code in the .done of that, but that failed.

JavaScript is not a language I'm super familiar with. C# is my forte so working with a  soft typed asynchronous language has been a challenge.

Edit: For those curious, the "parseList" function essentially just parses the object that gets returned and puts it into a 2d variable with headers. The "GetList" function pulls a sharepoint list's data. The end result of this project is to make a 3 line way to pull the data you want from a sharepoint list and use it in a way that's easier to understand.

Edit 2:

The following does not work

```
var heads = ["Title", "Artist", "Plays", "Added", "Genre"];
var gibbe = ["Title", "mz0o", "hd1f", "v9gk", "nphg"];
$.when(
array = GetList("Music", heads, gibbe);
).done(function(){

console.log("Array: ", array);
});
```

As it has the same result, returning Array as undefined then returning items with the expected raw data. It runs the .done before the function returns data.

Edit3:
Per ritaj I added async: false to the function and now it returns this

Items: Raw data
Array: Undefined

I went in and added a log to the function so now the end of the function looks like this

```
items = parseList(items, heads, gibberish);
console.log("Pre-return items: ", items);
return items;
```

And now it's giving me

Items: Raw Data
Pre-Return items: Formatted Data
Array: Undefined

At this point I think it's my issue. It seems to be running the code in the correct order now, but it's not returning the data for some reason.

Comment: You can use promises (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Or simply wrap all of your synchronous code into functions and put it inside of done

Comment: Either put your code inside ajax done or use Promises or Observables.

http://blog.scottlogic.com/2011/05/10/converting-between-jquery-deferred-and-rx-observable.html

Comment: Okay so I must be misunderstanding something. How would I wrap the function call in a .done or a promise? I  can just move the ajax call to the main script and not use it as a function, but that defeats the purpose.  

And calling the function in  a .when such as      
$.when( items = GetList(stuff, stuff, stuff); ).done(do things) doesn't work. The code still executes the .done before items has a value

Comment: `.done(function() { doWhateverYouWant(array) } `

Comment: However you do asynchronous programming (callbacks, `Promises`, `asynch`/`await`), the code that has to run after the asynchronous process repeats will have to be in a function.  (An `async` function, one passed to `promise.then`, or a callback passed to some asynchronous function.)  Unfortunately, there is no magic "make this synchronous" technique.

Comment: @ritaj Updated the op to show properly formatted code. Either I'm not understanding what you're saying, or that doesn't work for my current issue. I can just run the ajax call outside of a function and put the code in the .done, but the point was to take that 16 required lines of code for every list needed and break it down to 3 lines.

Comment: add a parameter to ajax call `async: false`

Comment: @ritaj now the behavior is just weird. So now it's running the console log after the function completes but. Well I updated the top to show with proper formatting. I think at this point it's executing in the order I want, but not giving me the behavior I want. I think your answer is the one I needed and now I just need to debug and find why the return isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with asynchronous programming in Javascript. What you want  will not happen. You need callbacks to retrieve
the result from asynchronous code.

What you can do is:

```
function GetList(listName, heads, gibberish, onSuccess) {
  var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+ listName + "')/items";
  $.ajax({
     url: siteUrl,
     method: "GET",
     headers: { Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" },
     success: onSuccess
  });
}

function _onSuccess(items) {
    // Code here, do what you want with items
}

var heads = ["Title", "Artist", "Plays", "Added", "Genre"];
var gibbe = ["Title", "mz0o", "hd1f", "v9gk", "nphg"];

GetList("Music", heads, gibbe, _onSuccess);
```